# Setting TaskExecutor for JMS component

Tags: java, apache-camel

I would like to set up my jms component to use a specific `TaskExecutor` (actually would rather use an `ExecutorService` but doesn't seem possible). However why I try to do so I get an error.

My spring has the following:

```
<bean id="jmsExecutorService" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor>....</bean>
```

My Route Builder has the following:

```
from("jms:queue:myQueue?concurrentConsumers=20&taskExecutor=jmsExecutorService")...
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a suitable setter for property: taskExecutor
     as there isn't a setter method with same type: String not a conversion possible:
     No type converter available to convert from type: String to the required type
     TaskExecutor with value jmsExecutorService
```

I have had a hard time finding a working example of setting the TaskExecutor. I would like to specify a specific TaskExecutor as I would like to name the threads in the thread-pool appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also posted to the Camel mailing list, where we have the answer
http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Setting-TaskExecutor-for-JMS-component-tp5731017.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick response to the noob question.